# UC_ERR_WRITE_UNMAPPED when emulation starts on binary

Tags: emulation, capstone

Whenever I try to emulate my obfuscated driver it fails at `uc_emu_start` with UC_ERR_WRITE_UNMAPPED. I get all success return codes on: `uc_mem_map` and `uc_mem_write` but when I call `uc_emu_start` ; I get the UC_ERR_WRITE_UNMAPPED error. So, I added a hook on the error code to see what address it was writing to and I found that it was: `0xfffffffffffffff8`. I don't understand why it is writing to this address because I put `0x1000` as my base address (`std::uint64_t BASE_ADDRESS = 0x1000;`) which is then used at
`uc_emu_start`. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

```
// EMU.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <unicorn.h>
#include "capstone/capstone.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>
#include "PE.h"
#include "BasicBlock.h"
#include "Optimizations.h"
#include "CCapstoneHelper.h"
static bool hook_mem_invalid(uc_engine* uc, uc_mem_type type, uint64_t address,
    int size, int64_t value, void* user_data)
{
    switch (type) {
    default:
        // return false to indicate we want to stop emulation
        return false;
    case UC_MEM_WRITE_UNMAPPED:
        printf(">>> Missing memory is being WRITE at 0x%" PRIx64
            ", data size = %u, data value = 0x%" PRIx64 "\n",
            address, size, value);
        // map this memory in with 2MB in size
        uc_mem_map(uc, 0xaaaa0000, 2 * 1024 * 1024, UC_PROT_ALL);
        // return true to indicate we want to continue
        return true;
    }
}
int main()
{
    try {
        // UNICORN
        uc_engine* uc;
       uc_err err;

        // CAPSTONE
        csh handle{};
        cs_insn* insn;
        //size_t count; 
        std::queue<uint64_t> Q;
        std::map<uint64_t, bool> seen;
        std::uint64_t BASE_ADDRESS = 0x1000;

        
#define MEGABYTES_TO_MAP 15
        
        std::cout << "[+] Starting emulation..." << std::endl;
        if (cs_open(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_64, &handle) != CS_ERR_OK) {
            throw std::runtime_error("cs_open failed");
        }

        if (uc_open(UC_ARCH_X86, UC_MODE_64, &uc) != UC_ERR_OK) {
            throw std::runtime_error("uc_open failed");
        }
       
        if (uc_mem_map(uc, BASE_ADDRESS, 2 * 1024 * 1024, UC_PROT_ALL) != UC_ERR_OK) {
            throw std::runtime_error("uc_mem_map failed");
        }




        cs_option(handle, CS_OPT_DETAIL, CS_OPT_ON);

       
        // get pointer to file from Init()
        insn = cs_malloc(handle);
        std::cout << "[+] Finding driver entry point..." << std::endl;
       PE::CPe pe = PE::CPe::CPe("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Driver\\Driver.sys");

   
       std::cout << "[+] Found: " << std::hex << pe.get_entry_point_address_relative_to_mapped_file() << std::endl;

       std::cout << "[+] Starting emulation..." << std::endl;
       BasicBlock::CBasicBlock block_buffer{};
       BasicBlock::_basic_block basic_block{};
       basic_block.start_address = pe.get_entry_point_address_relative_to_mapped_file();
    //   BASE_ADDRESS += pe.get_entry_point_file_offset();
        const std::uint8_t* addr = (std::uint8_t*) basic_block.start_address;
      
       // we are at entry point. Start emulation until we reach end of basic block?
       // At entrypoint, set start of basic block to entry point address.
       // Emulate until we reach a JUMP instruction
        std::cout << "[+] Removing anti-disassembly..." << std::endl;
        Optimizations::COptimizations optimizations;
        std::uint8_t anti_d_pattern[] = {0xEB, 0xFF, 0x64, 0x24, 0x08};
        std::uint64_t num_of_bytes_fixed = optimizations.remove_antidisassembly(anti_d_pattern, sizeof(anti_d_pattern), pe);
       
        uint64_t target = 0;
       size_t code_size = 0x1000;
       
       CapstoneHelper::CCapstoneHelper capstone_helper_obj;


       uc_hook hook;
       err = uc_hook_add(uc, &hook, UC_HOOK_MEM_WRITE_UNMAPPED, hook_mem_invalid, NULL, 1, 0);
      
       while (true) {
 
           std::uint64_t prev_base_address = BASE_ADDRESS;
          while (cs_disasm_iter(handle, &addr, &code_size, &BASE_ADDRESS, insn)) {
               if (capstone_helper_obj.is_cs_cflow_ins(insn)) {
                   basic_block.end_address = (std::uint64_t)addr;
                   break;
               }
               

           }

           
           std::uint32_t error;
           // write code and then some into memory
           //uc_mem_map(uc, prev_base_address, MEGABYTES_TO_MAP * 1024 * 1024, UC_PROT_ALL);
          // if (uc_mem_map(uc, BASE_ADDRESS, MEGABYTES_TO_MAP * 1024 * 1024, UC_PROT_ALL) != UC_ERR_OK) {
          
               err = uc_mem_write(uc, prev_base_address, reinterpret_cast<void*>(basic_block.start_address), (basic_block.end_address - basic_block.start_address));
               if (err != UC_ERR_OK) {
                  throw std::runtime_error("uc_mem_write failed");
              }
            
              
            // resolve file offset from base_address;
              

               err = uc_emu_start(uc, prev_base_address, prev_base_address + (basic_block.end_address - basic_block.start_address) , 0, 0);
               if (err != UC_ERR_OK) {
                   throw std::runtime_error("uc_emu_start failed");
               }



               /* TODO:
               1. Write anti-disassembly remover because capstone won't properly disassemble.
               Anti disassembly byte string: EB FF 64 24 08 (Removing EB byte results in " jmp    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]"
               Use file pointer to do operations before we disassemble with capstone.
               2. Add check for control flow instructions (look at PBA)
               */

          
       }

        
       










        
        uc_close(uc);
        cs_close(&handle);
        
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what();
        getchar();
        std::abort();
    }
    
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, too early in the morning and I confused hex and binary